# Finish activity when onPostExecute is called (in AsyncTask)

Tags: android-asynctask, drive

I use the GMS Drive sample demo.

I want to select a file (with Drive dialog open file), download the file, then finish the activity.

My problem is if I use finish() in the onActivityResult, I cannot get the result in my main activity, if I use finish() in the onPostExecute, the dialog is not closed, and I need to press "Cancel" to return to my main activity (with the result). I would like to return without pressing "cancel" button...

I use the RetrieveContentsActivity and PickFileWithOpenerActivity from the demo.

Here is my code :

```
public class RestoreActivity extends DriveActivity {

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_OPENER = 1;

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
            .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
            .setSelectionFilter(Filters.contains(SearchableField.TITLE, "settings"))
            .build(getGoogleApiClient());
    try {
        startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_OPENER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                DriveId driveId = data.getParcelableExtra(OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
                new RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask(RestoreActivity.this).execute(driveId);
            }
            finish();   // if I put finish() here, I cannot get the result in onActivityResult (main activity)
            break;
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

final private class RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask extends ApiClientAsyncTask<DriveId, Boolean, String> {

    public RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackgroundConnected(DriveId... params) {
        String contents = null;
        DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(), params[0]);
        DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult = file.open(getGoogleApiClient(), DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).await();
        if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            return null;
        }
        DriveContents driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(driveContents.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            contents = builder.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException while reading from the stream " + e.toString());
        }

        driveContents.discard(getGoogleApiClient());
        return contents;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("settings",result);
        if (result == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error");
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED,returnIntent);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "OK");
            setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
        }
        // if I put finish() here nothing happens, and dialog is still opened till I press "Cancel" button
    }
}
```

}

How can I return to the main activity after onPostExecute and stop intent DriveApi ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that I don't like : make it in 2 steps.

1. pick the file using the PickFileActivity from demo, return the driveId by declaring it public in MainActivity (**public static DriveId driveId**) and changing code like this :

   ```
   MainActivity.driveId = data.getParcelableExtra(OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
   ```
2. move the AsyncTask in my MainActivity.

If someone find another solution ?